# Why is Megillat Esther the only Megillah that is still read from parchment?

Tags: purim, yom-tov, megillat-esther

Originally, all of Tanac"h was written on parchment. Thus, all 5 Megillot read during the year were read from parchment.

Most minhagim that I have seen (Nusach Ahkenaz and Sefard) do not currently read any of the Megillot (i.e. - Eicha, Kohelet, etc.) from parchment, except for Megillat Esther.

(I know that there are some customs that still read all 5 from parchment, but it I snot the majority, as far as I know.)

Why and when did this custom change? And why is only Megillat Esther read from parchment?

Comment: I guess it is because it is the only one that there is a mitzva to read

Comment: Many schuls don't have the other four on hand. That simple. If ploni decided to donate an Eicha, or a Kohelet, Shir Hashirim, or Rut, I'm sure they'd lehn from it.

Comment: My *nusach* Ashkenaz *shul* reads all but *Eicha* from a *klaf* and we say *al mikra megillah* and *shehekhiyyanu*.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt some Shuls have haftorahs on a klaf and they do not lain from it (it is hard for them)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10695/4940

Comment: "Originally, all of Tanac"h was written on parchment. Thus, all 5 Megillot read during the year were read from parchment." How do you know this??

Comment: @magicker72 Why not Eicha?

Comment: @DoubleAA Something like "why would we invest in something we hope not to read from next year?". The last paragraph of [this article](https://www.torahmusings.com/2012/07/tisha-bav-megillat-eicha-2/) suggests a similar thought process.

Comment: @magic but if someone donated one and Tisha bav happened you'd use it? Just you won't use shul money to buy one?

Comment: @DoubleAA I imagine that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** *I removed the reference to the haftarah as it is not analogous to the megillah. However that discussion is found at [Reading the Haftorah From Printed Materials](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/711551/rabbi-josh-flug/reading-the-haftorah-from-printed-materials/) However, I have found references that speak of the other for megillos*

Megillas Esther has the requirements of reading from a klaf as part of the mitzvah and one would not fulfill the mitzvah if this were not done. THe other megillos do not have that requirement as part of a mitzvah. When printing became practical, then they began using printed copies just as was done with the Haftara (as seen in the linked article above).

[Megilla](http://www.aish.com/h/pur/m/48970631.html)

> 11) The entire Megillah must be read from a kosher scroll, written
>   with proper ink, parchment, markings (sirtut), etc. One who recites
>   the Megillah by heart has not fulfilled his obligation.

The other megillos are not required to be read from a klaf as pointed out by [The Reading of Eicha on Tisha B'Av](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/715592/rabbi-josh-flug/the-reading-of-eicha-on-tisha-b-av/)

This discussion goes into the details of whether or not it requires a bracha. However, during the course of the discussion, we see that the halacha of the other megillos does not require a klaf, unlike megillas Esther. See the Fourth reason of the Rama not to recite a bracha for the other megillos.

> The Book of Eicha is one of the five megillot (scrolls).  Masechet
>   Soferim 14:1, states that when one reads one of the five megillot, the
>   beracha of Al Mikra Megillah is recited.  R. David Avudraham, Tefillot
>   HaPesach codifies the statement of Masechet Soferim.  Ramban, Torat
>   Ha'Adam (Chavel ed. Pg. 258) applies the statement of Masechet Soferim
>   specifically to the reading of Eicha.  Nevertheless, R. Yosef Karo,
>   Beit Yosef, Orach Chaim 559, notes that common practice is to refrain
>   from reciting the beracha of Al Mikra Megillah on all of the megillot
>   with the exception of Megillat Esther.
>
> Rama, Teshuvot HaRama no. 35, addresses the practice of refraining
>   from the recitation of a beracha.  He presents four reasons for this
>   practice.  First, perhaps the beracha of Al Mikra Megillah is only
>   recited upon obligatory readings of a megillah.  If the megillah is
>   read because of a minhag, one does not recite a beracha.  [Rama does
>   note that the reading of Eicha can be considered an obligatory reading
>   since it is based on Talmudic sources.]  Second, there are different
>   versions of Masechet Soferim as to what beracha should be recited. 
>   One version is to recite Al Mikra Megillah.  Another version is to
>   recite Al Mikra Ketuvim.  Rama suggests that a tradition developed to
>   omit the beracha in order to avoid this question.  Third, Rama
>   questions whether it is actually appropriate to recite a beracha on
>   reading a megillah (aside from Megillat Esther).  Although Masechet
>   Soferim does endorse reciting a beracha upon recitation of the
>   megillot, Rama suggests that the statement in Masechet Soferim is
>   based on opinions and traditions that are not considered common
>   practice.  **Fourth, Rama suggests that one may only recite the beracha
>   of Al Mikra Megillah if one is reading from a text that is written on
>   parchment and was written according to the laws of writing a sefer
>   Torah.  Since most communities do not have megillot that are written
>   on parchment** (with the exception of Megillat Esther), they do not
>   recite the beracha of Al Mikra Megillah.
>
> Rama concludes that one should never recite a beracha on the megillot
>   (with the exception of Megillat Esther) even if they are written on
>   parchment.  He notes that if the only reason to refrain from reciting
>   the beracha is that they are not written on parchment, synagogues
>   would make it a priority to purchase a set of megillot.  Since we do
>   not find such a practice, it must be that one would not recite a
>   beracha on the megillot even if they are written on parchment.
>
> Magen Avraham 490:9, disagrees with Rama's conclusion and rules that
>   one should recite a beracha on the reading any of the megillot (except
>   Kohelet).  [Magen Avraham does not seem to require parchment in order
>   to recite the beracha.  Ostensibly, Magen Avraham is following his own
>   opinion (284:1) that there is no requirement to use parchment for the
>   Haftorah text (see "[Reading the Haftorah from Printed Materials](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/711551/rabbi-josh-flug/reading-the-haftorah-from-printed-materials/)").] 
>   Mishna Berurah 490:19, sides with the opinion of Rama that one should
>   not recite a beracha on the megillot.  However, he notes that one can
>   justify the practice of reciting a beracha if the megillah is read
>   from parchment.  The Vilna Gaon's personal practice was to read all of
>   the megillot from parchment and to recite a beracha (see Ma'aseh Rav
>   no. 175).  Those communities that follow all of the minhagim of the
>   Vilna Gaon recite a beracha on reading the megillah from parchment. 
>   [See R. Yechiel M. Tucatzinski, Sefer Eretz Yisrael 21:2.  R.
>   Tucatzinski implies that reading from a parchment is necessary
>   regardless of whether one plans on reciting a beracha.]

Comment: You have a partial answer, actually. The 1st part answers why specifically Esther is read from a klaf. It doesn't answer when or why the other megillot stopped being read from a klaf and why these were permitted. You seem to be citing halachot regarding haftarah, but I don't see how it relates to the other megillot on Yom Tov.

Comment: @DanF I brought in a link that shows that the other megillos are not required to be written on a klaf while discussing whether or not to say a bracha on them. I bolded the relevant part. In order to be understood, I did not edit out the rest of what I quoted.