# Bringing your own Megilah to shul

Tags: megillat-esther

I notice that some people like to bring "their own" Megila to shul. What is the reason for this? If they miss a word hear and there, they can always read it from a chumash, since one may read up to half the megilah by heart. (Shulchan Aruch Siman 690 Seif 3).

Comment: You probably should source that last claim, since that seems to be what you’re basing your entire question off of. Besides, the Mishnah (Megillah 2:1) rules explicitly that one may not read the Megillah by heart, and the Gemara (18a) doesn’t clarify that it means *the entire* Megillah.

Comment: related (or duplicate?) of [Why is Megillat Esther the only Megillah that is still read from parchment?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69669/11501)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, while one may read up to half - under certain condition - by heart, one does have to either **read or hear every single word**.

As the Shulchan Aruch says in the location you quote [סימן תרצ - דיני קריאת המגלה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_39.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2):

> **ג**: צָרִיךְ לִקְרוֹתָהּ כֻּלָּהּ, וּמִתּוֹךְ הַכְּתָב; וְאִם קְרָאָהּ עַל פֶּה, לֹא יָצָא. וְצָרִיךְ שֶׁתְּהֵא כְּתוּבָה כֻּלָּהּ לְפָנָיו לְכַתְּחִלָּה, אֲבָל בְּדִיעֲבַד אִם הִשְׁמִיט הַסוֹפֵר בְּאֶמְצָעָהּ תֵּבוֹת, אֲפִלּוּ עַד חֶצְיָהּ, וּקְרָאָם הַקּוֹרֵא עַל פֶּה, יָצָא

Secondly, filling in words by heart (or from a printed text) is בְּדִיעֲבַד - not the best way to do the Mitzvah.

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן קמא - הלכות מגלה ובו כ"ג סעיפים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0140_L2) puts is this way:

> **סעיף יג'** :
>   הַקוֹרֵא אֶת הַמְּגִלָּה, צָרִיךְ לְכַוֵּן לְהוֹצִיא אֶת כָּל הַשּׁוֹמְעִים. וְגַם הַשּׁוֹמֵעַ צָרִיךְ לְכַוֵּן לָצֵאת וְלִשְׁמֹעַ כָּל תֵּבָה וְתֵבָה, **שֶׁאֲפִלּו אִם רַק תֵּבָה אַחַת לֹא שָׁמַע, אֵינוֹ יוֹצֵא**. וְלָכֵן צָרִיךְ הַקּוֹרֵא לְהַשְׁגִיחַ מְאֹד, שֶׁבְּשָׁעָה שֶמַּרְעִישִׁין וּמְבַלְבְּלִין בְּהַכָּאַת הָמָן, יִשְׁתֹּק עַד יַעֲבֹר הָרַעַשׁ לְגַמְרֵי. **וּמִכָּל מָקוֹם רָאוּי וְנָכוֹן שֶׁיִהְיֶה לְכָל אֶחָד מְגִלָּה כְּשֵׁרָה, כְּדֵי שֶׁיֹּאמַר בְּעַצְמוֹ מִלָּה בְמִלָּה בְּלַחַשׁ, פֶּן לֹא יִשְׁמַע תֵּבָה אַחַת מִן הַקּוֹרֵא**. וְכֵן כָּל אִשָּׁה חַכְמַת לֵב שֶׁעוֹמֶדֶת בְּעֶזְרַת נָשִׁים, אִם אֶפְשָׁר, מַה טּוֹב לִהְיוֹת לָהּ מְגִלָּה כְּשֵׁרָה לִקְרוֹת מִתּוֹכָהּ, כִּי שָׁם קָשֶׁה לִשְׁמֹעַ, וְהַנָּשִׁים חַיָבוֹת כְּמוֹ הָאֲנָשִׁים‏

"Best to have a Kosher Megila so that one can whisper the entire text, thus ensuring that one doesn't miss any words."

That's besides for the added value that whispering the text prevents one from becoming drowsy and possibly spacing out and missing out on listening (as opposed to *hearing*) to the Megilla.