# Brachot on Kriat Megilla

Tags: minhag, blessing

Why when the Megillot of Shir Hashirim, Ruth, and Koheleth are read from a klaf are the brachot of al mikra megillah and sheichaynu made before the reading? Reading the megillot on those days is a minhag and not a mitzvah so why the brachot?

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10695/759

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See SA OC 490, 9 in annotations of RM Issarles:

> ונוהגין לומר שיר השירים בשבת של חול המועד, ואם שבת ביום טוב האחרון, אומרים אותו באותו שבת, וכן הדין בסוכות עם קהלת. ונוהגין לומר רות בשבועות (אבודרהם). והעם נהגו שלא לברך עליהם "על מקרא מגילה", ולא "על מקרא כתובים":‏
>
> ... The folk has the custom to read (Shir Hashirim in Pesach, Rut in Shavuot, Eicha in Yom Hakkipurim and Kohelet in Sukkot) without blessing, no "al mikra megila", neither "al mikra ketuvim".

The author wrote in Darke Moshe on the Tur (same siman):

> ואמרינן במסכת סופרים הקורא בחמש מגילות מברך על מקרא מגילה ואפילו היא כתובה בין הכתובים עכ"ל וכ"כ מהרי"ל וכ"ה בהג"מ הל' ט"ב וכן המנהג דלא כמרדכי שכתב פ"ק דמגילה דאם היא כתובה בין הכתובים ....‏
>
> They say in Masechet Sofrim, one who reads one of the five megilot blesses "al mikra megila",even if the megila is not an independent scroll but a part of a scroll of hagiography. The same is written in Maharil and in Hagahot Maymoniot... This disagrees with the Mordechai, who wrote that if the megila is a part of Hagiography scroll, they have to bless "al mikra ketuvim".

The Levush (a student of the RM Issarles) wrote:

> וכתב מורי רמא״י‏ ז״ל שהעם נהגו שלא לברך כלל על אלו המגילות, רוצה לומר שיר השירים ורות. ואיני יודע למה לא יברכו עליו. ועוד תמיהני עליו, היאך ידע זה המנהג כל כך בפשיטות? שהרי הכל קורין בלחש ומברכין בלחש, ומי הגיד לו שלא ברכו כולם? אם שמע שקצת מהם לא ברכו, שמא מחסרון ידיעה עשו, שלא קראו בהגהות מהר״א טירנא, ואותם שקראו בה ברכו? שהרי כתוב שם בפירוש שמברכין על אלו ב׳ מגילות.‏
>
> ...perhaps they (the folk who did not bless) did this by lake of knowledge. (The Levush seems to rule that even a yachid bless for himself)

The Magen Avraham sk 9 quotes a responsum of RM Issarles:

> וז"ל רמ"א בתשו' סי' ל"ד /ל"ה/ מהרי"ל ואבודרהם והג"מ פ"ה מהל' ט"ב כתבו לברך וכ"כ בד"מ לכן דקדקתי וכתבתי והעם נהגו כו' ולא כתבתי סתם וכן נוהגין כמ"ש בשאר מקומות וכן נ"ל מכמ' טעמים דדוקא איכה שהחזן קורא להשמיע לצבור מברך וכו' וכ"מ דעת המנהגים ועי"ל דדוק' כשהם כתובים כתקנה בקלפים בגלילה מברכין אבל בחומשין שלנו פשיטא שאין לברך וכו' עכ"ל
>
> ... They bless only when the Megila is readen publicly and on a scroll.

The Baer Heytev concludes, according to the Taz, that to blessing for those Megilot (excepted Ester) is a vain blessing as the OP seems to understand.

The Mishna Berura says that the Magen Avraham stated to bless for megilot excepted for Kohelet. The Gaon from Vlilna stated to bless even for Kohelet.

The Aruch Hashulchan explained not to bless because this minhag is not written in Gemara, following a rule stated in many poskim to skip blessings which aren't listed in Talmud (e.g. hanoten layaef koach, mekaddesh shimcha barabbim).

**Answer.** Following masechet Sofrim according to the understandind of Maharil and Hagahot Maymoniot, this minhag to read megilot on a scroll is enacted by chachamim, with a blessing.

Comment: so does that mean that it is like an in between a mnhag and a mitzvah akin to hallel on rosh chodesh and thats why a bracha is made

Comment: yes if I inderstand, good example!