# Reciting Shehecheyanu on other Megillot

Tags: vilna-gaon, shehecheyanu, 5-megilloth

[Ma'aseh Rav 175](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%98%D7%95%D7%91#%D7%A7%D7%A2%D7%94) records the following practice of the Gra regarding reading Shir HaShirirm on Pesach, Kohelet on Sukkot and Rut on Shavu'ot: the reader makes two blessings beforehand, *'al mikra megillah* and *shehecheyanu*.

What is the source for reciting *shehecheyanu*? None of the earlier sources that I've seen which discuss making a blessing on these *megillot* make mention of *shehecheyanu* (Machzor Vitri, Hagahot Maimuniyot, Mordechai, Maharil, Abudarham, Levush, Bach, Magen Avraham).

In fact, the earliest source for reciting *'al mikra megillah* is [Soferim 14:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.14.3?lang=bi), which then goes on to only mention reciting *shehecheyanu* for Esther ([14:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Tractate_Soferim.14.5?lang=bi)), strongly implying that the other *megillot* do not have a *shehecheyanu*.

So what is the Gra's source / rationale for reciting this blessing?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10695/do-we-say-a-mitzvah-bracha-before-reading-kohelet-what-about-other-non-purim

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81901/brachot-on-kriat-megilla

Comment: The Gra regularly added shehechiyanu to obscure mitzvot. See Maaseh Rav 102 and 103 and his biur to yd28 oc22 etc. Just guessing, but he probably wouldn't be bothered by people not mentioning it since it's a separate question and they might not have agreed with his general perspective on the bracha

Comment: Levush does have it https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A6